# Does anyone have an example Chainlink Large response Toml job specs for Chainlink node operators?

Tags: chainlink

Does anyone have an example of Chainlink Large response Toml job specs for Chainlink node operators?

The only example I could find was json:

```js
{
  "name": "large-word",
  "initiators": [
    {
      "id": 9,
      "jobSpecId": "7a97ff84-93ec-406d-9062-1b2531f9251a",
      "type": "runlog",
      "params": {
        "address": "0xc57b33452b4f7bb189bb5afae9cc4aba1f7a4fd8"
      }
    }
  ],
  "tasks": [
    {
      "jobSpecId": "7a97ff8493ec406d90621b2531f9251a",
      "type": "httpget"
    },
    {
      "jobSpecId": "7a97ff8493ec406d90621b2531f9251a",
      "type": "jsonparse"
    },
    {
      "jobSpecId": "7a97ff8493ec406d90621b2531f9251a",
      "type": "resultcollect"
    },
    {
      "jobSpecId": "7a97ff8493ec406d90621b2531f9251a",
      "type": "ethtx",
      "confirmations": 1,
      "params": {
        "abiEncoding": [
          "bytes32",
          "bytes"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Do we just change the Abi encoding?

any help would be much appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with a simple V2 direct request job, you just need to ensure your ABI and parameter encoding is correct, and matches what the contract expects, no *resultCollect* is needed for V2. In addition to this, you need to use the v0.7 onwards [Operator.sol](https://github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/blob/develop/contracts/src/v0.7/Operator.sol) as your oracle contract as opposed to the older [Oracle.sol](https://github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/blob/develop/contracts/src/v0.6/Oracle.sol), as this is the one that has the fulfillOracleRequest2 function that takes a bytes parameter for the data, as opposed to a bytes32 parameter (which limits the size of your response)

```
decode_log   [type="ethabidecodelog"
              abi="OracleRequest(bytes32 indexed specId, address requester, bytes32 requestId, uint256 payment, address callbackAddr, bytes4 callbackFunctionId, uint256 cancelExpiration, uint256 dataVersion, bytes data)"
              data="$(jobRun.logData)"
              topics="$(jobRun.logTopics)"]

decode_cbor [type="cborparse"
             data="$(decode_log.cborPayload)"]

// Then, we use the decoded request parameters to make an HTTP fetch
fetch [type="http" method=GET url="$(decode_cbor.fetchURL)"]
parse [type="jsonparse" path="$(decode_cbor.jsonPath)" data="$(fetch)"]

// Finally, we send a response on-chain.
// Note that single-word responses automatically populate
// the requestId.
encode_response [type="ethabiencode"
                 abi="(bytes data)"
                 data="{\\"data\\": $(parse) }"]

encode_tx       [type="ethabiencode"
                 abi="fulfillOracleRequest2(bytes32 requestId, uint256 payment, address callbackAddress, bytes4 callbackFunctionId, uint256 expiration, bytes data)"
                 data="{\\"requestId\\": $(decode_log.requestId), \\"payment\\": $(decode_log.payment), \\"callbackAddress\\": $(decode_log.callbackAddr), \\"callbackFunctionId\\": $(decode_log.callbackFunctionId), \\"expiration\\": $(decode_log.cancelExpiration), \\"data\\": $(encode_response)}"
                 ]

submit_tx  [type="ethtx" to="0xc57b33452b4f7bb189bb5afae9cc4aba1f7a4fd8" data="$(encode_tx)"]

decode_log -> decode_cbor -> fetch -> parse -> encode_response -> encode_tx -> submit_tx
```